# Google chrome doesn't want to remember passwords on websites with false HTTPS. Can I force it?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, credentials

My company uses a website with https but it's red.

google crome doesn't want to remember te password, can I force it to do so if I'm sure this is a legit site?